# Paste text from slide number placeholder on PowerPoint slide into Word

Tags: vba, powerpoint, vba7, vba6

I am trying to copy three things from a PowerPoint slide and paste them into Word (using a VBA Marco in PowerPoint): 1) Slide number, 2) Thumbnail image of the slide, and 3) the Slide notes.

I'm able to grab the slide notes by using `Placeholders(2)`, but I can't get the same approach to work when trying to copy the slide number placeholder on the slide. I can only get it working by providing the exact name of the shape `'Slide Number Placeholder 77'`.

I'm looking for pointers on how to copy the slide number placeholder on any arbitrary slide without having to know the exact name of the shape.

Thanks

```
Sub PPTtoWord()

' Copy slide 1, paste as picture onto slide 1, resize, and rename

ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Copy

Set mySlideCopy = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.Paste

With mySlideCopy

  .Name = "Slide Thumbnail"
  .Left = 0
  .Top = 0
  .Height = 400
  .Width = 200
 
End With

' Set up Word

Dim wdApp As Word.Application, wdDoc As Word.Document

    Set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    If wdApp Is Nothing Then Set wdApp = New Word.Application
    Set wdDoc = wdApp.ActiveDocument
    
' Copy slide number from a placeholder on slide 1 over to Word

Set myDocument = ActivePresentation.Slides(1)

' ********** This is where the problem is *****************
ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("Slide Number Placeholder 77").TextFrame.TextRange.Copy
' *********************************************************

wdApp.Selection.PasteAndFormat wdFormatPlainText
wdApp.Selection.Move

'  Copy slide thumbnail from slide 1 over to Word, then delete it

ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("Slide Thumbnail").Copy

wdApp.Selection.PasteAndFormat wdPasteDefault
wdApp.Selection.Move

ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("Slide Thumbnail").Delete

' Copy slide notes from slide 1 notes master over to Word

ActivePresentation.Slides(1).NotesPage.Shapes.Placeholders(2).TextFrame.TextRange.Copy
   
wdApp.Selection.PasteAndFormat wdPasteDefault
wdApp.Selection.Move


End Sub
```

(Eventually I want to put these three things into a table and repeat for all slides, but I need to get this working first.)

Comment: Unless you have some unusual numbering, you can simply use the .SlideIndex property for the slide, it's normally identical to the slide number. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.slide.slideindex

Comment: Thanks! I was able to solve it with: <br/>


`Dim oshp As Shape

With ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes

Set oshp = .AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 100, 100, 40, 20)

    oshp.TextFrame.TextRange.InsertSlideNumber
 '   oshp.Name = "Slide Num"'

End With`<br/>

<br/>
I then copy/paste Slide Num to Word and then delete the shape.